# very basic CSS won't listen to the HTML Div

Tags: html, css

I tried this but something wrong with the content div

it should be easy, but I don't get it..

still trying and looking for the answer tho..

the problem is I want to styling my Div id=content but the CSS won't get the output..

I tried to figure it how, but it worked only when I nested them like this

```
  <div id="content">
    <div id="contentwrap">
    <div id="outer">
    <div id="insider">
the content
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

so this is my code... please somebody help!!!

I tried this like 5 hours, just only a simple but un-understandable case!
and well I'm getting fater because of 2 boxes of pizza while thinking about this

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

<!-- header-->header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#wrap-logo {
  margin: 0;
}

<!--navigation-->.wedge {}

.navigation {
  top: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 720px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 5%;
}

.nav-head {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.nav {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 22%;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.nav:first-child {
  margin-left: 1.5%;
}

.nav:hover {
  padding: 3% 1%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

.nav.currentpage {
  padding: 3% 1%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

<!--content -->#content {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <div id="wrap-logo">
    Logo
  </div>
</div>

<header>
  <div id="wedge">
    <div class="navigation">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="nav currentpage"><a href="index.php">1</a></div>
        <div class="nav"><a href="#">2</a></div>
        <div class="nav"><a href="#">3</a></div>
        <div class="nav"><a href="#">4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!--content-->
<div id="content">
  a
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't get you!Can you be more clear?..Lets keep the pizza aside for a moment!

Comment: You're using HTML comments (`<!-- comment -->`) in CSS (where comments are denoted by `// comment`). CSS should just ignore these lines but browsers are weird in a way so this could be causing an issue.

Comment: LoL that was intermezzo man, so stressed out sorry for my English btw, i will edit the question

Comment: ahhh IT'S TRUE!!! JUST KNOW IT,,, god would be love u man... omg!!! i'm so silly LoL

Comment: _"the problem is I want to styling my Div id=content but the CSS won't get the output"_ -- can you rephrase that in English?  Seriously, you need to show what you want to achieve and what you are getting that isn't correct.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm sorry mate i can't think clearly because this is makes me stuck like 5 hours.. but anyway i get the answer... it was silly comment.. sorry to bother u, anyway thx for ur advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put HTML line comments in CSS!

Take out all the `<!-- -->` in your CSS and everything will work just fine!

Use `/* line comment here */` instead.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vkavj6t8/2/

Answer (score 0):

CSS can't get the comment from the HTML like

```
<!-- comment -->
```

CSS only read with this comment

```
/*comment*/
```

it's very basic but how silly i am.. sorry for troubling u guys

thx to @Sidney Liebrand and @Adam Buchanan Smith